# import js file inside .vue component loaded using httpVueLoader

Tags: vue.js

i want to not use webpak form my vue devlopement,
so there is 2 alternative
writting components as .js file or 
writing them as .vue file and use httpVueLaoder to load component as if they are .js file
with httpvueLoader think go grate untile the time i want to use an API inside my component 
ther i can not get the API
i have a Home.vue componet inside ther is a FormLot.vue component in witchi try to import API.js

```
<script>
let FormLot = window.httpVueLoader('./frontEnd/page/lot/FormLot.vue')
module.exports = {
    name:"Home",
     components: {FormLot:FormLot},
...    
};
</script>
```

in FormLot.vue

```
// _END_ is the absolut path to the site , soi can change it later
let API = import(_END_+'/api/api.js') // dont work return promise
import API from './frontEnd/api/api.js' // dont work componnet dont show at all :(

 let FormLotE1 = window.httpVueLoader(_END_+'/page/lot/FormLotE1.vue')

module.exports ={
    ...
};
</script>
```

API.JS

```
module.exports ={
   ...
};
```

API.JS

```
export default {
   ...
};
```

with API.js i tryed export default and module.export bothe dont work
nota
when using webpack API.js got been normaly imported and work fine

Comment: how did you try `export default`?

Comment: when reading about httpvueLoader they sait that export default dont work in .vue file , so we have to change it to module.exports =, thats is true for the .vue file,when my import .js file dont work i guess that it wos because my API.js used export default, so i changed it to module.exports

Answer (score 1):

when using import API from path httpVueLaoder dont work
so i tried to do

```
const API= import(path)
```

problem witch that ,API is promise ,wich can notbe used :(
using await dontsolve the problem even when using

```
const API = (async ()=> await import(path))()
```

my solution still to call import using await but not in the top of the script
i call it in the mounted() function

```
async mounted(){

                     API = (await import(_END_+'/api/api.js')).default

    },
```

note that you must use .default because import return a module :)
enter code here